# How do I pass an Action into a TestCase

Tags: nunit

I have an NUnit test

```
[TestCase(...)]
public void test_name(Action onConfirm)
{
   ...
}
```

What I want to do is pass an Action into this test in the TestCase attribute, but no matter what I try keeps failing.  I tried to put

```
() => SomeDummyMethodIDefined()
```

directly into the TestCase and that didn't work.

I created an Action

```
Action DummyAction = () => SomeDummyMethodIDefined();
```

and pass DummyAction into the TestCase and that didn't work.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a very rough example which I was inspired from reading the [NUnit docs here](http://www.pgs-soft.com/en/new-features-in-nunit-2-5-part-1-parameterized-tests/)

```
namespace NUnitLambda
{
    using System;
    using NUnit.Framework;

    [TestFixture]
    public class Class1
    {
        [Test]
        [TestCaseSource(typeof(SourceClass), "TestCases")]
        public void Foo(Action action)
        {
            action();
        }
    }

    public class SourceClass
    {
        private static Action t = () => Console.WriteLine("Hello World");

        public static Action[] TestCases = { t };
    }
}
```

Have a play around with the code, hopefully you will get what you want out of it. For the record, I was using NUnit 2.6.

EDIT:

You don't have to use `static` here either e.g.

```
public class SourceClass
{
    private Action t = () => Console.WriteLine("Hello World");

    public Action[] TestCases;

    public SourceClass()
    {
        TestCases = new Action[1];

        TestCases[0] = t;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! With C# 6.0 you could use nameof(SourceClass.TestCases) to make it strongly typed.