# Passing parameters into a unit test inside a T4 template

Tags: c#, unit-testing, t4

I have the following **T4** template file called **(MyTest.tt)** where `TestName`(String) and `MyAction`(Action) are parameters. Can I pass lambda action into the template?
How can I pass data into the parameters?

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>  
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(TargetPath)" #>
<#@ output extension=".Generated.cs" #>
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;

namespace Test.TestTemplate
{
    [TestClass]
    public class Test2
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void HAS_ACCESS_<#= "TestName" #>()
        {                       
            <#= MyAction.Invoke() #>                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with MyAction(Action) ? This is a delegate type? If so what is the purpouse of a delegate type used as pure text in the template ? Or you mean that this is just a name (String) for the delegate ?

Comment: Hi @vasiloreshenski with action I mean a lambda function.

Comment: which you will call like this <#= MyAction.Invoke() #> ?

Comment: yes, I will correct that. But how can I pass the parameters into the template?

Comment: Btw, when I try to save the template I get the error: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods

Comment: It is a bit strange to inject delegate/expression into a template. And the TestName can predefined or you can read it from file.

Comment: Yes, that´s true I was just hoping there would be a simple way to pass parameters into the template instead of letting the template call functions outside of it. I think it would be cleaner like that. But maybe that´s the way to go I just have to figure out how to do it. Thing is I need to trigger UICoded methods from within the unit test. Hence I was hoping I could pass a lambda action into the template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Injecting parameters into templates is probably not so easy. The execution context of a t4 template if you run them from visual studio is not accessible i think. They can be executed programatically, but i've never done it.

If you try to have parameterized t4 template i can think of several options at the moment.

**Option 1 - Predefine your data**: Define collection of anonymous types (just for easier prototyping) with two fields for the name of the test and the delegate to be invoked in your t4 template, then it is very easy to generate multiple tests from the collection.

```
<#
// define the collection
var testCases = new [] {
 new {name = "TestCase1", method = new Action(() => { /* your action body */ }) },
 etc
};
#>
```

then generate the tests from the testCases data.

```
<# foreach(var testCase in testCases) { #>
   [TestMethod]
   public void HAS_ACCESS_<#= testCase.name #> ()
   {
        <#= testCase.method() #>
   }

<# } #>
```

**Option 2 - Shared template:** You can define base t4 template which can be included and executed from another template. This can be your base template

```
 [TestClass]
 public class Test2
 {
    [TestMethod]
      public void HAS_ACCESS_<#= TestName #>()
      {                       
       <#= MyAction.Invoke() #>                
      }
 }
```

Note that **TestName** and **MyAction** are used as they are variables defined in the template. Now in second template you can do the following

```
<#
    string TestName = "TestCase1";
    Action MyAction = () => { };
#>
<#@ include file="{Yor tempalte name.tt}" #>
```

Where 'Your template name.tt' is actual name of the previous defined base t4 template.

This way you can define multiple t4 template which will call the base template with the provided arguments.

**NOTE - inject dll:** If you really need to call predefined method (you have mention **UICoded methods**) from already existing dll you can include the dll as follows in your template and then use what you need from the dll.

```
<#@ assembly name="$(TargetDir)Mydll.dll" #>
```

or

```
<#@ assembly name="C:/..../Mydll.dll" #>
```

I use the **first option** when i need to generate multiple tests from predefined data (when i know my test cases but is too much hand work which can be automated).

The **second option** i am using when i am generating c# classes (not so much for unit test generating) and don't want all of them to be in a single file.

Comment: Thanks for the example, I will have a better look at this!

Comment: probably the first option and assembly with the UICoded methods injected in the template is possible way to achive it.

Comment: How do you reference the assembly in the code? Do you use e.g. Mydll.methodName() My dll contains all my namespaces so it´s quite long. Do you know if its possible to use an alias for the dll in the code?

Comment: Yes, you use it as it was in normal c# class. Full name qualifier Namespace1.Namespace2...etc or you can include the namespace in the t4 tempate by using <#@ import namespace="Namespace1.Namespace2" #> and then use the types from that namespace directly.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using NUnit for this which you can get from NuGet.

You can use [TestCaseData](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestCaseData) in order to send parameterized objects. It has also been done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20682219/how-do-i-pass-an-action-into-a-testcase)

Note: I don't use T4. You may have to adjust the code a bit, but this is the idea.

```
namespace Test.TestTemplate
{
    [TestFixture]
    [TestCaseSource(typeof(TestTemplateData), "HasAccessData")]
    // Make the type as bool so you can run it against the NUnit .Returns
    public bool HAS_ACCESS_<#= "TestName" #>(string stringParameter, Action actionParameter)
    {
        <#= MyAction.Invoke() #>

        // Do something here with the parameters...
        // Remember you have to return here so the .Returns can assert against it.
        // No need to do Assert
    }
}
```

Then the data source file which contains your testing data

```
public class TestTemplateData
{
    // I assume you will use the same action all the time, so just
    // define it here
    private Action<int> square = (int x) => x * x;

    public static IEnumerable HasAccessData
    {
        get
        {
            yield return new TestCaseData
            (
                // This is the string parameter
                "Word",
                // Put whatever parameter you want for your action
                square(1)
            )
            .SetName("Name of this test case") // Test name
            .Returns(true); // What is the test expected to return

            // You can return multiple test cases this way
            yield return new TestCaseData
            (
                "Word",
                square(2)
            )
            .SetName("Name of this test case") // Test name
            .Returns(true); // What is the test expected to return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @AzzamAziz for the example. I wish I could use nUnit but what I didn't mention is that I am doing a UICoded unit test which is unfortunately not supported by nUnit. I just realized that :s